# how to adjust the Slider (from 0 to 70)

Tags: ios, uislider

I need to know how to make my slider scroll from 0 until 70 and showing the current value like in all iOS applications which use the UISlider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UISlider` has `minimumValue` and `maximumValue` properties, whose default values are 0.0 and 1.0, respectively. To set the slider to 70, using these defaults, you would set the slider's `value` to 0.70.

To actually show that value (70) on the screen, you would need to have a separate `UILabel` in your UI that you update when the slider value updates.

Answer (score 1):

You sHould do these two thing

```
label1.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f",slider1.value];

slider1.minimumValue=0;
slider1.maximumValue=100;
slider1.continuous=YES;
```